# Позиционирование элементов в PyQT

Tags: python, qt, gui, pyqt, qlayout

Хотел бы узнать как можно удобно позиционировать элементы, если пишешь небольшие классы без использования `Qt Designer`. 
Часто видел, что люди, которые здесь отвечают на вопросы по `Qt` пишут похожим образом.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class HelpDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(HelpDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        text_widget = QtWidgets.QLabel('anytext')
        btnOk = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Ок", clicked=self.hide)

        layout.addWidget(text_widget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(btnOk, 3, 1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Да, для позиционирования графических виджетов в Qt используют `менеджеров расположения` (`Layout Management`) https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html. В чем вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**Layout Management**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)
>
> Система компоновки Qt предоставляет простой и мощный способ автоматического размещения дочерних виджетов внутри виджета, чтобы убедиться, что они эффективно используют доступное пространство.
>
> ...

Это не зависит от размера класса, его просто надо применять на практике. 
Вот вам базовый пример - смотрите и изучайте.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QDialog,
    QDialogButtonBox, QFormLayout, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout,
    QLabel, QLineEdit, QMenu, QMenuBar, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QTextEdit,
    QVBoxLayout)


class Dialog(QDialog):
    NumGridRows = 3
    NumButtons  = 4

    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()

        self.createMenu()
        self.createHorizontalGroupBox()
        self.createGridGroupBox()
        self.createFormGroupBox()

        bigEditor = QTextEdit()
        bigEditor.setPlainText(
            "Этот виджет занимает все оставшееся пространство "
            "в макете верхнего уровня."
        )

        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.gridGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(bigEditor)
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Basic Layouts")

    def createMenu(self):
        self.menuBar = QMenuBar()

        self.fileMenu = QMenu("&File", self)
        self.exitAction = self.fileMenu.addAction("E&xit")
        self.menuBar.addMenu(self.fileMenu)

        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.accept)

    def createHorizontalGroupBox(self):
        self.horizontalGroupBox = QGroupBox("Horizontal layout")
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        for i in range(Dialog.NumButtons):
            button = QPushButton("Button %d" % (i + 1))
            layout.addWidget(button)

        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def createGridGroupBox(self):
        self.gridGroupBox = QGroupBox("Grid layout")
        layout = QGridLayout()

        for i in range(Dialog.NumGridRows):
            label = QLabel("Line %d:" % (i + 1))
            lineEdit = QLineEdit()
            layout.addWidget(label,    i + 1, 0)
            layout.addWidget(lineEdit, i + 1, 1)

        self.smallEditor = QTextEdit()
        self.smallEditor.setPlainText(
            "Этот виджет занимает около двух третей "
            "макета сетки. \n Смотрим соотношение `setColumnStretch`!"
        )

        layout.addWidget(self.smallEditor, 0, 2, 5, 1)   # 0, 2, 4, 1

        # QGridLayout.setColumnStretch(column, stretch)
        # Устанавливает растягивающий коэффициент столбца столбца для растягивания. 
        # Первый столбец - номер 0.
        #layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)      # label
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 10)      # lineEdit
        layout.setColumnStretch(2, 20)      # smallEditor
        self.gridGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def createFormGroupBox(self):
        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Form layout")
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Line 1:"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Строка 2, длинный текст:"), QComboBox())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Line 3:"), QSpinBox())
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app    = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    sys.exit(dialog.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]